# Make VS2017 to understand jsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2017, jsx

VS 2017 is supposed to understand jsx files. When I transitioned from 2015 to 2017, all my jsx files turned into a very long red underline. There where errors everywhere even though in vs2015 i didn't have any errors. I suppose that is because vs 2015 just didn't bother to "intellisense" the files in the first place, but I prefer to have no intellisense and a clean view, than have intellisense that considers everything is wrong.

I use webpack+babel to transpile and bundle my react components. When I buld with webpack everything goes fine. But the intellisense says everything is wrong.

In my web project there is a folder named 'React' under which all my react views and components are located.

When I import 3rd party components (not relative paths) vs 2017 intellisense says it can't find the modules.

[image]

But this is not happening to all files. In some files it can resolve the modules, in others it cannot.

What is going on here and how am I supposed to solve this problem?

Intellisense is broken so I had to disable highlighting syntax errors. It's better that way, but still I don't have intellisense (autocompletion, suggestions etc)

Answer (score 0):

You should download `react.d.ts` file so `Visual studio` could understand them.
For example download from here: [react.d.ts](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/modern/class/React.d.ts) or I think there is a `nuget` package also. 
Another solution is to use this syntax: `var react=require('react')` but you will not get intellisense this way, but at least you will get successfull build.

Comment: What is this file? What does it do? And what about all the other modules. It seems this is something like a polyfill for react. What about backbone, jquery, and all the other 3rd party libraries I use? Also, I build my files with webpack. I don't need typescript. I only want the text editor to properly highlight my code, properly indent it (the jsx indentation is horrbile) and properly intellisense it.

Comment: I was not able to get proper syntax inside jsx file alone. I didn't get syntax highlighting, intellisense, nothing. Then I created tsx file (which automatically creates jsx files anyway) and it helped me.

Comment: So, do you suggest renaming all my files to tsx and changing my webpack.config to set babel to understand tsx files as React files? Would that work?

Comment: Saving tsx files (If default Visual studio are turned on) would automatically (re)create jsx files, so probably will shouldn't do any changes.

Comment: Well, I think I will edit my react components in Visual Studio Code. I see it has better support for jsx

Comment: Great. BTW,  you don't need to be afraid of TypeScript. You don't have to use typescipt features because every javascript file is also typescript file, if you only to rename of extension (js to ts, jsx to tsx). But if you want you can gradually start using some typescipt features if you like. And it has nice features.